# Prove that the sequence of functions $g_{n}\in C[0,4]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

I want to show that the function defined by $g_n:[0,4]\to \Bbb{R}$, defined by\begin{align} g_n(t)=\begin{cases}0,& \text{if}\;0\leq t\leq 2,\\\dfrac{n}{2}(t-2),& \text{if}\;2\leq t\leq 2+\frac{2}{n},\\1 &\text{if}\;2+\frac{2}{n}\leq t\leq 4.\end{cases} \end{align}
is continuous and Cauchy.

**MY TRIAL**
The sequence of functions is clearly continuous by Pasting Lemma. Next, we show that the sequence of functions is Cauchy.

So, let $m,n\in\Bbb{N},$ be given such that $m\geq n.$ Then,

$$|g_m(t)-g_n(t)|=|0-0|+\left|\dfrac{m}{2}(t-2)-\dfrac{n}{2}(t-2)\right|\left|1-1\right|=0<\epsilon$$

I don't know if this is right. If not, kindly help please!

Comment: functions are continuous. sequences are Cauchy

Comment: to prove Cauchy, just calculate the max difference between $g_n$ and $g_m$. what exactly is your difficulty?

Comment: @mathworker21: Edited some things. Max difference?

Comment: wait, you're saying $|g_m(t)-g_n(t)| = 0$ for each $t$?

Comment: by max difference, what I mean is $\max_t |g_m(t)-g_n(t)|$. you want to show this is less than $\epsilon$ for $m,n$ large enough

Comment: What do you mean when you ask whether the sequence is Cauchy?  With respect to what metric?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: The absolute value metric!

Answer (score 1):

What meaning exactly do you assign to the sentence “the sequence $g_n$ is Cauchy”?

This sequence of functions converges pointwise to the function $h$ such that $h(x)=0$ if $0 \leq x \leq 2$ and $h(x)=1$ otherwise.

Now $h$ is not continuous whereas every $g_n$ is. So there cannot be max-norm convergence.

Edit: Just to provide some even more explicit argument because it does not seem to be accepted that the space of continuous functions from $[0,4]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is complete for the max-norm.

$g_n\left(2+\frac{2}{2n}\right)=\frac{n}{2}\frac{2}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}$, while $g_{2n}\left(2+\frac{2}{2n}\right)=1$. 
Thus the max-norm of $g_n-g_{2n}$ is not lower than $\frac{1}{2}$, hence the sequence is not Cauchy.

Comment: C([0,4]) is complete for the max-norm.

Comment: Besides, I do not have neough reputation to comment your post, but I fail to see how you can have $(N-n)/N < 1/N$.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you are thus proving that the max-norm of $|g_n-g_m|$ is lower than $(N-n)/n$, which would be negative?

Comment: John B: I do not have another question. I am not convinced by user289143’s proof and I cannot comment it.

Comment: User289143: then you cannot have $|N-n|<1$.

Comment: @Mindlack: Thanks but I want to prove that the sequence of functions, is Cauchy not convergent. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike: as I said, $\mathcal{C}([0,4])$ is complete for the max-norm, so being Cauchy is equivalent to converging (in he max-norm, thus pointwise) to a continuous function.

Comment: @Mindlack is right: $C([0,4])$ is complete with respect to the max-norm, hence Cauchy is equivalent to convergence... In fact there's the reason I made a mistake in bounding the max-norm of $g_n-g_m$, because the sequence is not convergent. If you want to prove that this sequence is Cauchy, but not convergent you should use another norm. Sorry for my error

Answer (score 0):

A sequence is Cauchy if for every $\epsilon$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n, m > N$ we have $|g_n-g_m|< \epsilon$.
Now let $m > n$. How does the function $(g_m-g_n)(t)$ look like?
\begin{align}
(g_m-g_n)(t)= \begin{cases}
0 & if\  0 \leq t \leq 2
\\(\frac{m}{2}-\frac{n}{2})(t-2) & if \ 2 < t \leq 2+\frac{2}{m} 
\\1-\frac{n}{2}(t-2) & if\ 2+\frac{2}{m} < t \leq 2+\frac{2}{n} 
\\ 0 & if\ 2+\frac{2}{n} < t \leq 4
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Now $||g_m-g_n||_1=\int_2^{2+\frac{2}{m}}|(\frac{m}{2}-\frac{n}{2})(t-2)|dt+\int_{2+\frac{2}{m}}^{2+\frac{2}{n}}|1-\frac{n}{2}(t-2)|dt$ 
If we compute explicitly the integrals we get $||g_m-g_n||_1=\frac{m-n}{m^2}+\frac{(m-n)^2}{nm^2}=\frac{m-n}{mn}<\frac{m}{mn}=\frac{1}{n}$
Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and we have $||g_m-g_m||_1<\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$ and this proves the sequence is Cauchy

Comment: Could you please explain why |N-n| < 1?

Comment: Edited the answer with the $||\cdot||_1$ norm, to prove the space is not complete